ASP.NET Boilerplate EF Unable to determine the relationship
I started a new project by downloading the latest aspnetboilerplate solution from their site using MVC.
As soon as I add this code below to the WebDbContext I get the error also below. Even with no code inside that block I get the error.
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
}


DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to determine the
relationship represented by navigation 'User.CreatorUser' of type
'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this
property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.' was thrown while
attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported
at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728


You could try add the base method:
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

